# How to create a hexbin polygon over a world map with a geom_sf object in R?

Tags: r, sf, sp, hexagonal-grid, hexagon-binning

I have global data with over 180,000 data points. For every pair of coordinates I have a value, and many times I have multiple values at the same coordinates (see example of the dataframe df). I want to plot this data using hexagonal grids onto a world map and have been struggling. The statbinhex option ggplot doesn't let me set the grids to be 1000 square kilometers and it only counts the number of points within a hexbin rather than the mean of all values within a hexbin so I have switched to other options. Right now I am trying to grid the world map using the spsample function from the package 'sp' but I keep running into errors.

Data:

```
df<-structure(list(Z = c(3.23, 3.518, 3.518, 3.518, 3.518, 3.518, 
3.518, 1.961, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 
0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845, 0.9845), latitude = c(-5.333, 
-19.01134381, -16.81667, -20.578928, -20.578928, -20.578928, 
-20.578928, 11.068441, 42.65, 59.6111, 55.8498, 58.6388, 57.0064, 
56.0202, 57.2875, 59.5252, 63.8363, 59.6032, 60.6532, 63.7764, 
59.3615, 62.6603, 58.9813, 58.9988, 58.984, 63.5407, 62.3942, 
59.36, 59.7953, 68.3704, 57.3549, 59.6111, 59.6111, 59.6068, 
59.6068, 59.6068, 63.6589, 59.169, 59.7762, 59.7762, 56.6949, 
56.2811, 61.6237, 56.3035, 56.7949, 56.6454, 65.5021, 59.8754, 
59.0856, 55.7247, 56.7308, 59.5479, 56.7237, 56.7821, 58.5819, 
59.5112, 67.8864, 67.8864, 59.0272, 58.9797, 60.2414, 59.0464, 
59.0805, 59.7875, 55.6308, 42.64, 42.534, 42.60166667, 41.2874, 
65.256706, 42.68333333, 42.61138889, 47.12, 63.3, 49.13547, 66.287, 
66.336, 66.468, 66.697, 66.968, 67.076, 67.566, 67.668, 67.679, 
67.939, 68.033, 68.455, 68.455, 68.501, 68.576, 68.881, 68.992, 
69.117, 69.141, 69.141, 69.203, 69.406, 69.426, 69.458, 69.512
), longitude = c(141.6, 146.2214001, 145.6333, 145.483398, 145.483398, 
145.483398, 145.483398, 76.509568, 77.47, 13.9202, 14.2217, 16.0795, 
14.4578, 14.6835, 17.9708, 16.2606, 20.127, 13.8554, 15.7272, 
20.8167, 13.4909, 17.399, 15.1313, 15.0579, 14.7382, 19.7277, 
17.7196, 13.4549, 17.5859, 18.7693, 15.762, 13.9202, 13.9202, 
13.8814, 13.8814, 13.8814, 20.3222, 15.1416, 18.3233, 18.3233, 
13.1492, 16.0232, 17.4425, 14.7285, 16.5662, 12.7691, 22.0001, 
18.0014, 14.6461, 14.1954, 13.0661, 17.5769, 12.8976, 12.8581, 
14.8691, 16.883, 22.2536, 22.2536, 14.9963, 15.0096, 14.48, 15.0569, 
14.9042, 17.6261, 13.5288, 2.09, 2.465, 1.093611111, 24.6651, 
31.904297, 1.205833333, 1.063888889, 6.63555, -150.5, 2.63457, 
36.865, 36.014, 35.334, 34.347, 29.208, 41.126, 33.391, 33.617, 
33.654, 32.91, 34.921, 35.344, 35.344, 28.733, 29.408, 33.02, 
29.031, 36.062, 29.242, 29.242, 33.455, 30.21, 31.057, 31.5, 
30.464), country = c("New Guinea", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "India", 
"Kyrgyzstan", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "France", "France", "Spain", "Greece", "Russia", 
"Spain", "Spain", "France", "USA", "France", "Russia", "Russia", 
"Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", 
"Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", 
"Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", 
"Russia", "Russia")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

World map:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
```

Hexbinninng the world map (this is where my code doesn't work and the hexbinning can't be executed, I also don't know how to make sure the sizes of the hexbins are 1000 square kilometers):

```
size <- 100
hex_points <- spsample(world, type = "hexagonal", cellsize = size)
hex_grid <- HexPoints2SpatialPolygons(hex_points, dx = size)


Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spsample’ for signature ‘"sf"’
```

My plan is to create polygon that is a hexbin or hex grid of the world that are 1000 km squared per hexbin and then intersect my data points with the polygon shape file and then plot the mean of of all points within the a hexbin across the world.

Would anyone know how to do this?